# How to run windows console application in java code using exec() method?

Tags: java, runtime.exec

how use Runtime.getRuntime().exec()?

I try:

```
try {
    String[] callAndArgs = {"path\\program.exe","arg1","arg2","arg3"}
    System.out.println("before");
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(callAndArgs)
    System.out.println("in");
    p.waitFor();
    System.out.println("after");
} catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("catch io: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            System.out.println("catch ie: " + ie.getMessage());
        }
```

And program doesn't work. Output:

```
before
in
after
```

hm? help ;p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this (classic) article: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html

Comment: This is a link-only answer and would have no use if (or when) the link dies.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help too (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=681779),

```
import java.lang.* ;

 public class MyJavaClass
 {
 public void runCmd(String[] args)
 {
 String cmd = "/home_dir/./my_shell_script.sh" ;
 Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime() ;
 Process pr = run.exec(cmd) ;
 pr.waitFor() ;
 BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( pr.getInputStream() ) ) ;

 while ( ( String line ; line = buf.readLine() ) != null ) 
 {
 System.out.println(line) ;
 }

 }

 }
```